# How to create a PDF catalog object to embed XML using Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, object, ghostscript, catalog

Does anyone know how to create a PDF catalog object to embed XML in the PDF file using Ghostscript?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a /Metadata pdfmark to add Metadata (which is what I assume you mean by 'embed XML') to the Catalog of a PDF file.

However, the Ghostscript pdfwrite device doesn't currently support the Metadata pdfmark, so this is not possible.

Comment: Is this still up to date, or does Ghostscript support the Metadata pdfmark by now? I couldn't find any information on this.

Comment: It hasn't been added. If someone wants to do so and submit a patch I'll be delighted to review it, and commit it when I'm happy with it.